# Ошибка деконстрактора объекта в pair

Tags: c++

Программа работает отлично,но при завершении (return 0) и попытке деконстрактора сработать на объект класса в pair выдает ошибку:

> HEAP[program.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000021B54F40000, 0000021B54F50CA0 )

Вот полный код программы:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include "IntSet.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    size_t temp = 0;

    IntSet intset1;
    IntSet intset2;



    intset1.pushBack(1);
    intset1.pushBack(2);
    intset1.pushBack(2);
    intset1.pushBack(5);
    intset1.pushBack(6);    // [1, 2, 5, 6]

    intset2.pushBack(6);
    intset2.pushBack(8);
    intset2.pushBack(2);
    intset2.pushBack(15);
    intset2.pushBack(27);   // [6, 8, 2, 15, 27]

    IntSet* intset3 = intset1.relative_complement(intset2); // [1, 2, 5, 6] / [6, 8, 2, 15, 27] = [1, 5]
    IntSet* intset4 = intset1.union_(intset2);  // [1, 2, 5, 6] + [6, 8, 2, 15, 27] = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 15, 27]

    pair<IntSet, IntSet> p = intset1.even_odd_division(intset2);


    temp = intset3->size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
        cout << (*intset3)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    cout << "\n" << std::endl;

    temp = intset4->size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
        cout << (*intset4)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

IntSet.h

```
#ifndef INT_SET_H
#define INT_SET_H


class IntSet {
public:
    IntSet();
    ~IntSet();
public:
    size_t size() const;
public:
    void pushBack(const int value);
    void remove(size_t index);
    int search(int num);
    IntSet* union_(IntSet& object_1);
    IntSet* relative_complement(IntSet& object_1);
    std::pair<IntSet, IntSet> even_odd_division(IntSet& object_1);
public:
    int operator[](size_t index);
private:
    int* arr_;
    size_t size_{};
    size_t capacity_{};

    void addMemory();
};

#endif // !INT_SET_H
```

IntSet.cpp

```
#include <utility>
#include "IntSet.h"

void IntSet::pushBack(const int value) {
    if (search(value) == -1) {
        if (size_ >= capacity_) addMemory();
        arr_[size_++] = value;
    }
}

void IntSet::remove(size_t index) {
    for (size_t i = index + 1; i < size_; ++i) {
        arr_[i - 1] = arr_[i];
    }
    --size_;
}

int IntSet::search(int num) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        if (arr_[i] == num) {
            return (int)i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

IntSet* IntSet::union_(IntSet& object_1) {
    IntSet* NewIntSet = new IntSet;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        NewIntSet->pushBack(arr_[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < object_1.size(); i++)
    {
        NewIntSet->pushBack(object_1.arr_[i]);
    }

    return NewIntSet;
}

IntSet* IntSet::relative_complement(IntSet& object_1) {
    IntSet* NewIntSet = new IntSet;
    int index = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        NewIntSet->pushBack(arr_[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < object_1.size(); i++)
    {
        index = NewIntSet->search(object_1.arr_[i]);
        if (index >= 0) NewIntSet->remove(index);
    }

    return NewIntSet;
}

void IntSet::addMemory() {
    capacity_ *= 2;
    int* tmp = arr_;
    arr_ = new int[capacity_];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i) arr_[i] = tmp[i];
    delete[] tmp;
}

int IntSet::operator[](size_t index) {
    return arr_[index];
}

size_t IntSet::size() const {
    return size_;
}

std::pair<IntSet, IntSet> IntSet::even_odd_division(IntSet& object_1) {
    IntSet EvenIntSet;
    IntSet OddIntSet;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if (arr_[i] % 2 == 0) EvenIntSet.pushBack(arr_[i]);
        else OddIntSet.pushBack(arr_[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < object_1.size(); i++) {
        if (object_1.arr_[i] % 2 == 0) EvenIntSet.pushBack(object_1.arr_[i]);
        else OddIntSet.pushBack(object_1.arr_[i]);
    }

    return std::make_pair(EvenIntSet, OddIntSet);;
}

IntSet::~IntSet() {
    delete arr_;
}

IntSet::IntSet() {
    arr_ = new int[1];
    capacity_ = 1;
}
```

Comment: Рекомендуется приводить *минимальный* пример. Вряд ли найдется много желающих разбираться в таком большом коде... Скорее всего, где-то некорректно работаете с памятью. Например, у вас нет ни конструктора копирования, ни оператора присваивания, при нетривиальной работе с памятью через указатель. Уже сомнительно...

Comment: Harry, хорошо, в следующий раз это учту. А решение проблемы нашлось - при возвращении объектов через pair вызывается деконстрактор, который потом вызывается еще раз в конце.

Comment: Подсказка нужно реализовать правило трёх. Или отказаться в классах от голых указателей

Comment: KoVadim, правило реализовал, но как это поможет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написал @Harry, у Вас проблема не в деструкторе, а в отсутствии конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания копированием в классе - т.е. правило трёх Вы *не реализовали*.  [правило трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))
Когда вы сами его не определяете, компилятор делает конструктор копирования по умолчанию, который просто делает копию полей. Т.е. просто копирует значение указателя на буфер, не копируя сам буфер.

```
std::pair<IntSet, IntSet> 
IntSet::even_odd_division(IntSet& object_1) 
{
    IntSet EvenIntSet;  // создали 2 локальных объекта, выделили память под массив
    IntSet OddIntSet;

    // заполнили их
    return std::make_pair(EvenIntSet, OddIntSet); // а теперь при создании пары делаются копии объектов - копируются указатели.
} // а теперь первоначальные объекты уничтожаются и память под массивы освобождается

main()
{
  pair<IntSet, IntSet> p = intset1.even_odd_division(intset2); // если бы вы обратились к массивам из этой пары, то была бы ошибка

// в конце программы пара уничтожается, вызываются деструкторы и пытаются освободить память, которая освобождена ранее
}
```

Кроме того у Вас утечки памяти в этих функциях:

```
IntSet* IntSet::union_(IntSet& object_1) 
{
    IntSet* NewIntSet = new IntSet;
    return NewIntSet;
}
IntSet* IntSet::relative_complement(IntSet& object_1) 
{
    IntSet* NewIntSet = new IntSet;
    return NewIntSet;
}
```

Вы динамически создаете объекты, но не уничтожаете. Просто программа маленькая и негативные эффекты не успевают возникнуть.
Также, ошибка в деструкторе. Выделяя память под массив - `new[]`, нужно удалять через `delete[]`

```
IntSet::~IntSet() {
    delete[] arr_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При возврате объектов через pair вызывается деконстрактор, который так же вызывается и при завершении исполнения программы, пытаясь удалить то чего уже нет.

Comment: Вопрос в том - а почему так происходит?